# Byte Size MisMatch: Writing Character Array in a struct to a binary file in C

Tags: c, struct, byte, binaryfiles

I have following structure:

```
typedef struct{
    int32_t loc;
    char value[2];
    int32_t left;
    int32_t right;
} Node;
```

Say my node has loc =0 : value= NW : left = 1 : right =2
I wrote the structure as the following :

```
//Writing Array of STruct to a Binary File
FILE *fileptr;
fileptr = fopen(filename, "wb");
if (fileptr != NULL) {
fwrite(Node, sizeof(Node),noOfNodes , fileptr);
fclose(fileptr);
```

Upon reading the file using UNIX od command ,

```
od -b xyz
```

I get the following output:

```
000 000 000 000 116 127 000 000 001 000 000 000 002 000 000 000
```

To my understanding, the number of bytes to store the structure should be 4+2+4+4=14 given character in C is 1 byte long . But the output has 16 bytes. Is my understanding incorrect.?

Comment: Did you search for that question? E.g. use the search keys "sizeof struct [c]".

Comment: Thank You. This is a duplicate of the question mentioned.